# Windows 10 regularly playing the "disconnect" sound

Tags: windows-10, system-sounds

On my Windows 10 desktop, I keep hearing this sound, now about every 30 minutes, sometimes multiple times in a row :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjkQzPsKv1Y

This is the sound played when disconnecting hardware, isn't it ?

How can I figure out where this comes from ? The Event Viewer that Windows offers as a standard app does not seem to tell me, or I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Test by disconnecting peripherals one at a time until it stops. Check the cables, plugs & sockets on that one. If you also have some kind of dock/hub, don't forget to include that in your tests.

Comment: 1. Check Event logs, particularly for USB-related warnings or  errors. Nirsoft's *FullEventLogView* can help to show all logs in one flat view. 2. Check for an overloaded USB hub that can't provide sufficient current by removing one device ata a time.

Comment: I have disconnected all USB things. The only devices left are, as far as I can tell, mouse and keyboard. The sound doesn't play often enough that I can afford to disconnect them and wait; though if it continues and I start to go mad (a distinct possibility), I might do that. _Nirsoft's _FullEventLogView_, tough a great recommendation in and of itself, stalls at loading after some thousand entries loaded and never finishes opening, so it's unusable for me right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to have been my mouse, out of all devices. Who knows exactly what it was up to. I figured this out thanks to [Nirsoft's **USBDeview**](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) (download 64-bit [here](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usbdeview-x64.zip)) which showed me that my mouse had the exact time at which I heard the sound in the column **Registry time 1**, whatever that means - probably the time of the last important event.

After two or three times of that coincidence, I plugged it out and then back in (in a different port, actually)
Maybe one of those two things helped - the problem seems solved, for now.